# C# equivalent of "use windows authentication"?

Tags: c#, .net, email

What is the C# equivalent of "use windows authentication" ? Is it this -

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

or 

smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

**EDIT -** this "use windows authentication" is often seen in microsoft products like SQL server, SSIS etc. I was wondering what it means in the context of sending mails. I saw one GUI for a simple SMTP mail sender which has a checkbox for "use windows auth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials returned by `DefaultNetworkCredentials` represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default network credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.

Comment: For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) - Usually means not all the time. So what are the exceptions then ?

Answer (score 1):

**smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;**
details are here : [SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)